# Integrating class into my existing code or not? Tkinter, python 3

Tags: python-3.x, database, tkinter, tkinter-entry, python-class

I have this GUI application that I have been obsessing about for over a week now and I think it is slightly harder than what I can manage with the limited programming/python knowledge I have gained so far - however, I just can't stop thinking about it and it is driving me insane that I can't figure it out.

I have created a GUI with Tkinter which is a Todo-list application. However, every task in the application must have some information associated with it.

So let's say we create a task called **"Homework"**.

I want to associate some attributes with **Homework**.

So, among others, some attributes would be **"Impact"** which represents the impact of completing the task on a scale from 0-10 (e.g. 10: I will fail my class if I don't complete my **Homework** task.), and deadline - which is self-explanatory. Those are just 2 of the attributes I want (there will be more though).

So as far as I have come to understand, this would be a great time to utilize [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

If I understand it correctly, I would have to create a `class Task:` and then set the attributes for every instance of `Task` to something.

I created the GUI before I became familiar with classes and some of the attribute information I want to associate with a given task can already be specified in the GUI (without any functionality) after creating a task, but I don't know how to use that information and connect it to the given task so that it has the functionality that I want.

I want to be able to enter a task, specify some attributes associated with that task, and then I want to be able to 'summon' that task and its' associated attributes for some simple math and/or sorting.
I only want the user to see that task itself - the calculations/sorting will just happen behind the scenes.

*My question:*
Should I do this with classes or is there a more beginner-level approach to this which would be easier to implement into my already existing code?
I really, really want to figure out how to go about this so any qualified pointers or in the right direction or examples, explanations, etc. will be truly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
from tkcalendar import *
import tkinter.messagebox # Import the messagebox module
import pickle # Module to save to .dat
import tkinter as tk

TASKS_FILE = "tasks.dat" ##Where the task strings are saved
task_list = [] ##Don't know what I am doing yet
impact_number = []  ##Don't know if this could be useful

root = tk.Tk() # ?????
root.title('SmaToDo') # Name of the program/window
# ROOT WINDOW
# Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
 
# Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)
 
# Positions the window in the center of the page.
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))


def new_task():
    def add_task():
        global task
        global impact_window
        task = entry_task.get() # we get the task from entry_task and we get the input from the entry_task type-field with .get()
        if task != '': # If textbox inputfield is NOT empty do this:
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
            entry_task.delete(0, tkinter.END) # 
            task_window.destroy()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Whoops', message='You must enter a task')
            task_window.destroy()
    
    task_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    task_window.title('Add a new task')
    task_label = tk.Label(task_window, text = 'Title your task concisely:', justify='center')
    task_label.pack()
    # Entry for tasks in new window
    entry_task = tk.Entry(task_window, width=50, justify='center')
    entry_task.pack()
    # Add task button in new window
    button_add_task = tk.Button(task_window, text='Add task', width=42, command=lambda: [add_task(), impact()])
    button_add_task.pack()



def impact():
        global impact_next_button
        global impact_window
        global impact_label
        global impact_drop
        global options
        global select

        impact_window = Toplevel(root)
        impact_window.title('Impact')
        options = StringVar()
        options.trace_add
        task_label = tk.Label(impact_window, text=str(task), font='bold')
        task_label.pack()
        impact_label = tk.Label(impact_window, text = 'Specify below the impact of completing this task \n (10 being the highest possible impact)', justify='center')
        impact_label.pack()
        impact_drop = OptionMenu(impact_window, options, '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')
        impact_drop.pack()
        impact_next_button = tk.Button(impact_window, text='Next', command=connectivity)
        impact_next_button.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
        def select():
            global impact_next_button
            global impact_window
            global impact_label
            global impact_drop
            global options
            impact_number.append(str(task) + options.trace_add('write', lambda *args: print(str(task)+' '+ 'impact' + ' ' + options.get())))
            options.set(options.get())
        
    

     
def connectivity():
    impact_window.destroy()
    clicked = StringVar()
    clicked.set('Select')
    global connectivity_next_button
    global connectivity_window
    global connectivity_label
    global connectivity_drop
    connectivity_window = Toplevel(root)
    connectivity_window.title('Connectivity')
    task_label = tk.Label(connectivity_window, text=str(task), font='bold')
    task_label.pack()
    connectivity_label = tk.Label(connectivity_window, text = 'Specify below the connectivity this task has to other tasks\n (e.g. tasks you can not complete unless you have completed this task)', justify='center')
    connectivity_label.pack()
    # var1 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(connectivity_window, text="Each task from list must be 'checkable' in this window").pack() # variable=var1).pack()

    connectivity_next_button = tk.Button(connectivity_window, text='Next', command=lambda: [Proximity(), select()])
    connectivity_next_button.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)

def Proximity():
    connectivity_window.destroy()
    global proximity_button
    global proximity_window
    global proximity_label
    global proximity_drop
    global cal
    global proximity_output_date
    proximity_window = Toplevel(root)
    proximity_window.title('Proxmity')
    task_label = tk.Label(proximity_window, text=str(task), font='bold')
    task_label.pack()
    proximity_label = tk.Label(proximity_window, text = 'Specify a deadline for when this task must be completed', justify='center')
    proximity_label.pack()
    cal = Calendar(proximity_window, selectmode='day', year=2021, month=4, day=27)
    cal.pack()
    def get_date():
        proximity_output_date.config(text=cal.get_date())
    proximity_date_button = tk.Button(proximity_window, text='Pick date', command=get_date)
    proximity_date_button.pack()
    proximity_output_date = tk.Label(proximity_window, text='')
    proximity_output_date.pack()
    proximity_button = tk.Button(proximity_window, text='Next', command=manageability)
    proximity_button.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)

def manageability():
    print('Deadline:'+' '+cal.get_date())
    proximity_window.destroy()
    clicked = StringVar()
    clicked.set('Select')
    global manageability_next_button
    global manageability_window
    global manageability_label
    global manageability_drop
    manageability_window = Toplevel(root)
    manageability_window.title('Manageability')
    task_label = tk.Label(manageability_window, text=str(task), font='bold')
    task_label.pack()
    manageability_label = tk.Label(manageability_window, text = 'Specify how difficult this task is to complete \n (0 being extremely difficult and 10 being extremely easy)', justify='center')
    manageability_label.pack()
    manageability_drop = OptionMenu(manageability_window, clicked, '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')
    manageability_drop.pack()
    manageability_next_button = tk.Button(manageability_window, text='Next', command=urgency)
    manageability_next_button.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)

def urgency():
    pass
    



def delete_task():
    try:
        task_index = listbox_tasks.curselection()[0]
        listbox_tasks.delete(task_index)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Oops', message='You must select a task to delete')

def save_tasks():
    tasks = listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size())
    pickle.dump(tasks, open('tasks.dat', 'wb'))




# Create UI
your_tasks_label = tk.Label(root, text='THESE ARE YOUR TASKS:', font=('Roboto',10, 'bold'), justify='center')
your_tasks_label.pack()

frame_tasks = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame_tasks.pack()

scrollbar_tasks = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame_tasks)
scrollbar_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)

listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(frame_tasks, height=10, width=50, font=('Roboto',10), justify='center') # tkinter.Listbox(where it should go, height=x, width=xx)
listbox_tasks.pack()

listbox_tasks.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tasks.set)
scrollbar_tasks.config(command=listbox_tasks.yview)


try:
    tasks = pickle.load(open('tasks.dat', 'rb'))
    listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    for task in tasks:
        listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
except:
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Phew', message='You have no tasks')

# Add task button
button_new_task = tkinter.Button(root, text='New task', width=42, command=new_task)
button_new_task.pack()


button_delete_task = tkinter.Button(root, text='Delete task', width=42, command=delete_task)
button_delete_task.pack()


button_save_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text='Save tasks', width=42, command=save_tasks)
button_save_tasks.pack()



















root.mainloop() # Runs the program - must be at the very buttom of the code
```

Some people on here have already helped me out a tremendous amount which I truly appreciate.

Comment: Well You don't necessarily need classes, You could also use dictionaries to store the information and it would be pretty easy to access and somewhat easy to add (since indexing because keys have to be different), otherwise if You feel classes will help use them. I only am "worried" about the use of `global` since they can lead to issues so it would be great to fix that which is what classes can help with but otherwise You can create classes just as templates too, however just so You know that it is possible to just use dictionaries. and I wrote the whole comment without realizing that You use.

Comment: also just so You know `mainloop()` doesn't have to be a the bottom it is just that everything after `mainloop()` will be executed when window is closed. also there is no point of that huge gap between `mainloop()` and the rest of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made some sample code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Label, Canvas, Scrollbar, OptionMenu, Toplevel, StringVar
import pickle


class Task:
    def __init__(self, name, type_, importance):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type_
        self.importance = importance


try:
    with open('saved_tasks.dat', 'rb') as file:
        task_list = pickle.load(file)

except FileNotFoundError and EOFError:
    with open('saved_tasks.dat', 'w') as file:
        pass
    print('Could not locate the file or the file was empty. A new file was created.')
    task_list = []

task_types = ['Misc', 'Math', 'Science', 'Economics', 'Biology', 'Homework']


def show_tasks():
    for widget in task_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    for task in task_list:
        Label(task_frame, text=f'{task.name} | Type: {task.type} | Importance: {task.importance}').pack(fill='x')


def open_add_task():
    win = Toplevel(root)
    win.focus_force()

    Label(win, text='Write task name').grid(column=0, row=0)
    Label(win, text='Choose type of task').grid(column=1, row=0)
    Label(win, text='Choose importance of task').grid(column=2, row=0)

    entry = Entry(win)
    entry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')

    type_var = StringVar(value=task_types[0])
    OptionMenu(win, type_var, *task_types).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nsew')

    imp_var = StringVar(value=1)
    OptionMenu(win, imp_var, *range(1, 10+1)).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='nsew')

    def add_task():
        task_list.append(Task(entry.get(), type_var.get(), imp_var.get()))
        show_tasks()

    Button(win, text='Add Task', command=add_task).grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')


def sort_tasks():
    type_ = sort_type.get()
    importance = sort_imp.get()
    order = asc_desc_var.get()

    for widget in task_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    for task in task_list if order == 'Ascending' else task_list[::-1]:
        if type_ == 'All' and importance == 'Any':
            Label(task_frame, text=f'{task.name} | Type: {task.type} | Importance: {task.importance}').pack(fill='x')
        elif type_ == 'All':
            if importance == task.importance:
                Label(task_frame, text=f'{task.name} | Type: {task.type} | Importance: {task.importance}').pack(fill='x')
        elif type_ != 'All':
            if type_ == task.type and importance == 'Any':
                Label(task_frame, text=f'{task.name} | Type: {task.type} | Importance: {task.importance}').pack(fill='x')
            elif type_ == task.type and importance == task.importance:
                Label(task_frame, text=f'{task.name} | Type: {task.type} | Importance: {task.importance}').pack(fill='x')


root = Tk()

btn_frame = Frame(root)
btn_frame.pack(fill='x')

sort_type = StringVar(value='All')
OptionMenu(btn_frame, sort_type, 'All', *task_types).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

sort_imp = StringVar(value='Any')
OptionMenu(btn_frame, sort_imp,'Any', *range(1, 10+1)).grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='nsew')

asc_desc_var = StringVar(value='Ascending')
OptionMenu(btn_frame, asc_desc_var, 'Ascending', 'Descending').grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='nsew')

Button(btn_frame, text='Sort', command=sort_tasks).grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')

Button(btn_frame, text='Add New', command=open_add_task).grid(column=3, row=0, rowspan=2, sticky='nsew')

task_frame_main = Frame(root)
task_frame_main.pack()

task_frame = Frame()
canvas = Canvas(task_frame_main)
canvas.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=task_frame, tag='task_frame', anchor='nw')
scrollbar = Scrollbar(task_frame_main, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('task_frame')))

show_tasks()

root.mainloop()

try:
    with open('saved_tasks.dat', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(task_list, file)
        print('File saved.')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'Exception was raised:\n{e}')
```

The main part here is the `Task` class, as You can see it is pretty small and that was the whole point, it doesn't have to be anything large. And the `task_list` can be easily serialized using `pickle` and easily loadable and it will keep those classes with their given attributes.

If You have any other questions, ask.

**Explaining everything (or most at least):**

First import everything You need and I like to do it like this when working with tkinter.

Then I defined `task_list` which will be used to store added tasks, and this can and probably should be replace by a file so You would read a file and then append the saved tasks to this list or just use json or pickle to import the file as a list which makes it easier. Anyways, then I just created a list to store all the types of tasks, it can be modified and again this is not as necessary but the list can be loaded from a file for example if there is an option to add another type (which requires quite some coding) it would be great to save them to a file so the info is saved.

**Now about `class Task`**:
this class doesn't have a lot of attributes, in fact just three to store basic stuff like `name` of the task, `type` of the task and how important it is.

There is not much to this but to mention it is possible to use for example `pickle` module and apply it to the `task_list` (which will store instances of `Task`) and it will serialize this object while keeping its attributes so when loading from `pickle` it will still be possible to access the object the same way.

**Now moving on to the `show_tasks()` function.**
So this is a general function for just showing everything that is appended to the `task_list` a.k.a. all tasks. This function puts `Label`s on the frame specified below but first it deletes everything off that frame because otherwise it will append all the items each time which means that it will grow exponentaly (You can test if You want by removing the first loop and adding a few tasks).

**Next is `open_add_task()` function** which is just for adding tasks.
It starts by creating another window `Toplevel` and puts focus on it. (sometimes I like to `bind` such windows so that when user clicks out of the window and this window loses focus close it so that there are not multiple such windows laying around but that is up to You).

Then I created a few labels that help users indicate what is asked from them.

Then I placed entry so that user can type in the task name and then so to avoid user typing error I gave them a choice to choose which category and importance they want so that they don't mistype something.

Then I defined a function (`add_task()`) for collecting data from user inputs, creating the class instance and appending it to the `task_list`. And it finishes with creating a Button that calls this function.

**Onto `sort_tasks`.**
This function is linked with widgets on root so there is the reference. so first get what the user has inputed and store in variables for easier reuse. Again user input is made easier by just giving choices. Again all widgets are cleared and then comes the sorting/logical part which probably can be improved and I didn't add the option to sort by importance number (so how high is it) so it sorts by time added (again there is no exact time but just order in the list is the time added). The logic could be improved but it mostly does what it is supposed to do (it was late and I couldn't properly think) but yeah there is not much to explain just step through it yourself.

**Next bit is the main window** which is not inside any functions as to not use `global`. first I initiated `Tk()` which is the basic and at the end there is `.mainloop()` used - the basic stuff. Then there is a lot of frames used to help organize the widgets and then all the widgets are added in this case I'm talking about the widgets that contribute to `sort_tasks()` function. So added all the choice menus and the button to execute `sort_tasks`. And a button to call `open_add_task()`.

**Next bit is the sort of main frame** where all the tasks are shown. There is canvas which is important, because a `Frame` cannot be scrolled itself, whereas canvas can be scrolled so essentially what happens, is that a frame gets added to the canvas and the `scrollregion` is set to the `Frame` size. Then added the scrollbar (will add link to this).

And that is pretty much it.

**EDIT:**
Added functionality for saving and reading file so that tasks can be saved and loaded. For some reason the file has to be loaded after `Task` because apparently otherwise it throws an error which I don't completely understand but I dealt with it by moving class above the whole thing. I also found an issue where when new tasks are added and they exceed the visible frame limit, scrollbar does not work, but then again opening the file  again it works fine, so that could be dealt with. Also as You can see I added save function after `mainloop()` so that whenever user closes the window it saves tasks to file. (added to sources)

**Sources:**

- [General tkinter info about widgets (I mostly use this)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)
- [Very good documentation of tkinter](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/)
- [Info about OptionMenu (1st source does not have this and 2nd source is a bit limited)](https://www.educba.com/tkinter-optionmenu/)
- ["Scrolling Frame" (there are other sources too)](https://blog.teclado.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/)
- [Pickle module (as it is noticeable it is not entirely safe but...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Wow, this was so nice of you and more than I expected. I am studying the sample code right now to try and understand everything. So far I understand most of it but will probably ask a couple of questions. 

In regard to your proposition to explain further, you are more than welcome - I will definitely read it closely!

Comment: I added a bit of explanation

Comment: SO nice of you - thank you!
Not sure I understand how exactly the task entered (in the entry widget) becomes an object of `Task`.

I can certainly see that the 
`task_list.append(Task(entry.get(), type_var.get(), imp_var.get()))
        show_tasks()`
has similar structure as 
`__init__(self, name, type, importance)` (the order of the arguments i mean) - so maybe I kind of understand it.

The `task` part of  
`for task in task_list:
        Label(task_frame, text=f'{task.name} | Type: {task.type} | Importance: {task.importance}').pack(fill='x')`
confuse me

Comment: string that is retrieved from the entry is just stored as an attribute of `Task`. Object is `Task` and it has attribute `name` which is set as the entry string. about that loop. Basically looping over the list in this manner means that each iteration task will be an item from the list. So it is almos like every iterations temporarily assigning `task = task_list[index]` and in this case it is also a `Task` object so it would be similar to `task = Task()` therefore `task.attribute` can access the current items attribute for example `.name`. Or which part was confusing exactly?

Comment: If i have a question to something related to this code but not the original question, what is the etiquette? - Do make another question thread or?

Also by the way @Matiiss - you helped me out *so* much with this. I hope you feel that I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: If You have questions related to this code but a different issue just post another question. You can also then link it here so that I can take a look at it. Otherwise if questions about my code or the issue here You can just ask them here. Other than that I am glad I could help You.

Comment: I have a question related to this. You mentioned that pickle could easily be used to store every class instance of a task added.

Can you elaborate on that part by any chance?

Comment: yeah, that is actually a pretty simple detail: basically first You would `import pickle` and then write to a file which I will demonstrate quickly

Comment: I edite the code to add functionality of saving tasks to a file using `pickle`